# Android Admob Requests 4-5 times higher than impressions

Tags: android, admob, ads, native-ads, impressions

my app uses admobs native express ads, every 4th row in a recipe list is showing an ad. I preload the ads before showing them to reduce the loading time. That causes that an Ad is requested even if it is not shown and the requests are much higher that the impressions. 
What causes that for Google? Is this a reason to ban the Account or do they serve less valuable Ads?